Select pairs with highest amount
I'm trying to select rows, where neither A nor B have an entry with more €:
This is an example of my data



Column A
Column B
€




A
B
100


B
A
100


C
B
80


B
C
80


D
E
75


E
D
75



And this is the desire output. Because B have a higher value in column € pair up C with B is not possible.



Column A
Column B
€




A
B
100


B
A
100


D
E
75


E
D
75



I tried rank() over (partition by...order by ...) but did not get any results.
The real data ("ok" marks qualifying rows):
Origen   ---   Destino  ---          Dinero     
 2   --------     13    -------      822205 € ok  
13   --------      2    -------      822205 € ok   
32   --------     13    -------      794909 €   
13   --------     32    -------      794909 €   
27   --------     32    -------      774035 € ok   
32   --------     27    -------      774035 € ok   
 2   --------     32    -------      740558 €   
32   --------      2    -------      740558 €   
30   --------     13    -------      717471 €   
13   --------     30    -------      717471 €   
27   --------     13    -------      703739 €   
13   --------     27    -------      703739 €   
17   --------     13    -------      695366 €   
13   --------     17    -------      695366 €   
30   --------     27    -------      694234 €   
27   --------     30    -------      694234 €   
 2   --------     27    -------      686425 €   
27   --------      2    -------      686425 €   
17   --------     30    -------      663328 € ok
30   --------     17    -------      663328 € ok


Because B/A or A/B have a higher €, therefore B/C or C/B should be dropped from the data? Is that the logic? IF so, could it be stated that for any unqiue origen or destino in an origen/destino pairing only keep the pairing that using that unique value that has the max() amongst any pairing? What would happen if there was another entry of A | C | 10000 ? Would A/B pairing still be viable with its 100 entry? Maybe it would help if you used your "real data" and shared its desired results.

I took the liberty to clarify your question as I understood it. Please fix if I misunderstood.

This only returns rows where no other entry exists that has the same a or b and a higher eur:
SELECT *
FROM   tbl x
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM tbl y
   WHERE (y.a = x.a OR y.b = x.b)
   AND    y.eur > x.eur
   );

But for what you seem to need, traverse the table top down (sorted by dinero). Every pair of rows after the first pair potentially depends on previous picks. Not easily implemented with pure SQL (set-based logic). You need a procedural solution.

'Every pair of rows after the first pair potentially depends on previous picks' that exactly what i need, thanks for your contribution.

The following SQL produces the desired output:
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE input_data (
  column_a TEXT,
  column_b TEXT,
  amount INTEGER)
  ON COMMIT DROP;

INSERT INTO
  input_data (column_a, column_b, amount)
VALUES
  ('A', 'B', 100),
  ('B', 'A', 100),
  ('C', 'B', 80),
  ('B', 'C', 80),
  ('D', 'E', 75),
  ('E', 'D', 75);

WITH
  maxes AS (
    SELECT
      column_a,
      column_b,
      amount,
      GREATEST(MAX(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY column_a),
               MAX(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY column_b)) max_member_amount
    FROM
      input_data
  )
SELECT
  column_a,
  column_b,
  amount
FROM
  maxes
WHERE
  amount = max_member_amount;

The query determines the greater of the maximum amount for each member of a pair and then filters the rows by selecting only those where amount equals the maximum associated with both members.
Note: Each row in the original post has a complementary row with the first two column values swapped, but this is not mentioned as a guaranteed data characteristic. If all rows are guaranteed to have a complementary row, then the call to GREATEST(...) can be replaced with either of the passed arguments; e.g., MAX(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY column_a).

Thanks for the contributions, i really apreciate it. As Erwin said 'Every pair of rows after the first pair potentially depends on previous picks', i´trying python to solve the problem.

@Caminerin, have you tried the approach I provided? If it results in the desired output, then a procedural approach isn't necessary. If it didn't return the desired rows, then please comment with a description of where it fails.
